# Get 7 days oldest record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query for get data 7 days oldest but failed with 'between'. my query:

```
SELECT b.sequence_number, b.message
FROM test.tab1 a, test.tab2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id 
AND a.delivery_date between (select min(delivery_date) from test.tab1) 
and (select min(delivery_date)-7 from test.tab1)
```

but this query can't get result. how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want last 7 days records from current date then query will be

```
    SELECT b.sequence_number, b.message
    FROM test.tab1 a, test.tab2 b
    WHERE a.id = b.id 
    AND a.delivery_date>=current_date - interval '7 days'
```

but if want 7days from you min date then it would be

```
SELECT b.sequence_number, b.message
        FROM test.tab1 a, test.tab2 b
        WHERE a.id = b.id 
        AND a.delivery_date>=(select min(delivery_date)-7 from test.tab1) and a.delivery_date <=(select min(delivery_date) from test.tab1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the between order, smaller one should be first then larger one

```
SELECT b.sequence_number, b.message
FROM test.tab1 a, test.tab2 b
WHERE a.id = b.id 
AND a.delivery_date between (select min(delivery_date)-7 from test.tab1)
and (select min(delivery_date) from test.tab1)
```

Comment: Would there really be a lower `tab1.delivery_date` than the `MIN(tab1.delivery_date)` ?